# To sum values from multipile workbooks with multiple worksheets

Tags: vba

I have multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets.I wrote a code in a newworkbook.All the workbooks have the same format.I need to do sum in a new workbook for multiple cells .Please help me with a code.I got a subscript out of range error.I dont have any experince of coding.

```
Private Sub Intra_Group_Exp1()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fileName As String
    Const FOLDER As String = "C:\Sushant_Files\"
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    fileName = Dir(FOLDER, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0

        If Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "xls" Then
            i = i + 1
            Dim currentWkbk As Excel.Workbook
            Set currentWkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)
            Dim P As Integer
            Dim q As Integer

            For P = 10 To 32
                For q = 2 To 19
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Intra Group_Exp").Cells("p,q").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Intra Group_Exp").Cells("p,q").Value + currentWkbk.Sheets("Intra Group_Exp").Cells("p,q:p,q").Value
                Next q
            Next P
            currentWkbk.Close
        End If
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main error is the following: You should address cells like `worksheet.Cells(p, q)` instead of `worksheet.Cells("p, q")`. The latter passes over the string `p, q` and not the content of the variables!

Having said this, it's much better to simple use `.PasteSpecial` with the options Values and Add. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252224/most-efficient-way-to-add-cell-values-across-congruent-ranges-in-vba/20254317#20254317)

So give this code a try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Intra_Group_Exp1()
    Const FOLDER As String = "C:\Sushant_Files\"
    Const cStrWSName As String = "Intra Group_Exp"
    Const cStrRangeAddress As String = "B10:S32"

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim wbSource As Workbook

    Dim fileName As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(cStrRangeAddress)

    fileName = Dir(FOLDER, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0

        If Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "xls" Then

            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)

            wbSource.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range(cStrRangeAddress).Copy
            rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd

            wbSource.Close
        End If
        fileName = Dir
    Loop

ProgramExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

As you can see, I added a few other improvements, hope it helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter for the code.I tried the code but I got the subscript out of range error.Please help.

Comment: please remove the `On Error...` statement and run it again - in which line does the code stop?