# Sum multiple workbooks from multiple worksheets using VBA without choosing manually

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to sum multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets with the same format. So far, I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742440/sum-cell-values-from-multiple-workbooks-with-multiple-worksheets-macro/). Although I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265237/to-sum-values-from-multipile-workbooks-with-multiple-worksheets) and also [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/568134-sum-cells-multiple-files-same-folder.html) links trying to get a good and short idea, the first one was working nice, so I followed.

It was going pretty well so far with the post I mentioned first. However, there are one (small) problem that I could not get the answer anywhere. How can I make the code to work without having to select the files? I have they all listed in a column in the workbook called "Main", and they are all in the same folder, however, I don't know how to get them automatically, without having to manually select.

For instance, I wanted to take the files (and their address) names in, for example, Sheet(1), Range("A1:A100") in the Workbook "Main".

Can anyone give me a hand? This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub Results()

Dim WS_Count As Integer 'not being used
Dim FileNameXls, f
Dim wb As Workbook, i As Integer

'locate where are the Templates and how many sheets they have
Range("Template").Select
ncol = ActiveCell.Column
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
lastcolumn = ActiveCell.Column
numSheets = lastcolumn - ncol

'Name of the First Template
Business = Cells(2, ncol)

Windows("StressTestPlatform.xlsm").Activate

'THIS IS WHERE I'M ASKED TO SELECT THE FILES
FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each f In FileNameXls
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
     For i = 3 To numSheets
         wb.Worksheets(i).Range("C5:H93").Copy 
         'The Range must be changed accordingly to the template being used
         Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Sheets("Results").Range("C5:H93").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True,     Transpose:=False
     Next i
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next f

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you file names include the full path or just the file?  Are all of the workbooks in the same folder?

Comment: Are we talking multiple workbooks, multiple sheets, or multiple workbooks with multiple sheets?

Comment: @jbarker2160 I have a cell with the path and I have another cells with the names of the files, I thought I could do something like Path & Name in the code.                                    Tbizzness I'm talking about several excel files with several worksheets. Multiple workbooks with multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the full file paths stored in a range somewhere, why not just loop through that range and open each file?

```
Dim TemplateRange as Range
Dim r as Range

Set TemplateRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A100")
'^^ Change this to wherever your list of files is stored.

'You can eliminate the GetOpenFilename dialog entirely
'FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

'Instead, just loop through the template range one by one and get
'each filename and proceed with the rest of your code as before
For Each r In TemplateRange
    FileNameXls = r.Value2
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileNameXls)

    '
    'The rest of your code as before
    '
Next r
```

If your template range has the workbook names, but not the full file path, you'll have to do a little extra work and get the directory of your Main workbook (assuming all the other files are in the same directory), and then append the workbook name to that.